# Image header issue facing

Tags: php, header

I have issue that when i am inserting the dynamic text into the existing image i mean creating dynamic text into the image here is the code:

```
<?
include("header.php");
include("menu.php");

     $rImg = imagecreatefrompng("../images/test.php");
     $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 0, 0, 0);
     imagestring($rImg,5,126,22,"test",$cor);
     imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);

include("btSlider.php");
include("footer.php");
?>
```

but i have issue that i don't want to use header output `header('Content-type: image/png');` the above code show me the garbage values. If i want to show the image for the following code what should i do.

If i run this its work

```
<?
     $rImg = imagecreatefrompng("../images/test.php");
     $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 0, 0, 0);
     imagestring($rImg,5,126,22,"test",$cor);
     header('Content-type: image/png');
     imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);
?>
```

i want to add the header and footer how could i do this and display the image on header and footer included file and also save the `rImg varaiable`.

I am beginner in the php that(s) why i was facing difficulties.

**Updated:
I also want to know that how could i enter multiple text on the image ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image generation code should be in it's own file.  You can then reference the php/image src using HTML..

**image.php**

```
<?php
   $rImg = imagecreatefrompng("../images/test.php");
   $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 0, 0, 0);
   imagestring($rImg,5,126,22,"test",$cor);
   //header('Content-type: image/png');
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   //imagepng($rImg,NULL,100);
   imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);
```

**the_page.php**

```
<?php

    include("header.php");
    include("menu.php");
    include("btSlider.php");
    include("footer.php");
```

**header.php/footer.php**

```
<img src="image.php" alt="This is the php generated image" >
```

***NOTE*** in your code sample, you are sending a png header `header('Content-type: image/png');` and rendering a jpeg with `imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);`

Comment: can you tell me how could i add more then 1 text into image please help

Comment: why dont you ask another question?

Comment: i didn't ask because it has just one line or should i open new question please recommended me..

Comment: `imagestring($rImg,5,126,22,"test",$cor);
imagestring($rImg,5,146,22,"test 2",$cor);`

Comment: thanks so much its too much helpful I like your post thanks soo much

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image embedded onto your page you can use a dataurl as your image src.

```
<?php
     $rImg = imagecreatefrompng("../images/test.php");
     $cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 0, 0, 0);
     imagestring($rImg,5,126,22,"test",$cor);
     ob_start();
     imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);
     $imgData = ob_get_clean();
?> 
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($imgData); ?>"/>
```

Comment: can you tell me how could i add more then 1 text into image please help

Comment: @MKDEV Add another call to imagestring after the first with different parameters

Comment: thanks so much i like it, its solve my problem. warm regards.